# using plotly in offline mode in jupyter notebook (using nbcovert --execute) opens IDE (vscode)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, plotly, nbconvert

I am kinda confused why this is happening if running a jupyter notebook (using nbconvert --execute) with the following code:

```
for key in dict:
   data = [go.Bar (x = dict[key].values(),
                   y = dict[key].keys(),
                   orientation = 'h')]

   layout = go.Layout(title = key, showlegend = False)
   fig = go.Figure(data = data, layout = layout)
   plotly.offline.plot(fig, filename= plots_path + key + '_plotly.html')
```

always leads to starting vs-code.
Does anyone experienced that issue before ?
How can I suppress it because I do the plotting in a loop and it is quite annoying to close more than 10 vs-code windows after each run.

Apparently it has to do something with the writing to html if I comment the last line out no vs-code windows are popping up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:
`plotly.offline.plot(fig, filename= plots_path + key + '_plotly.html', auto_open=False)`

Default behavior is it will try to find a program to immediately open the html file.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the fast reply! It worked :) I wonder why my system chose to open the HTML with vs-code and not with chrome...

Comment: If you need you can change the default application associated with .html files like this: https://techforluddites.com/windows-10-change-the-default-programs-for-opening-files/